# Hard link to soft link

Tags: files, filesystems, symlink, hard-link, ln

Can one force `ln` not to follow a soft link in its first argument?  For example, in the following I would like `hard` to be a hard link *to the soft link `soft`*:

```
$ mkdir dir
$ ln -s dir soft
$ ln soft hard
ln: soft: Is a directory
```

I know about `ln -h`, but this only prevents `ln` from following soft links in the *second* argument.

Comment: Works for me on GNU/Linux. What system are you on?

Comment: @ilkkachu They are showing the error that `ln` on a BSD system would produce. GNU `ln` also does this on BSD systems (`gln: soft: hard link not allowed for directory`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default on your system, `ln` resolves the source fully if it is a symbolic link.  There is a standard option, `-P`, that prevents it from doing this:

```
$ mkdir dir
$ ln -s dir soft
$ ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x  2 myself  wheel  512 Sep 21 22:39 dir
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myself  wheel    3 Sep 21 22:39 soft -> dir
```

```
$ ln -P soft hard
$ ls -il
total 4
129605 drwxr-xr-x  2 myself  wheel  512 Sep 21 22:39 dir
129606 lrwxr-xr-x  2 myself  wheel    3 Sep 21 22:39 hard -> dir
129606 lrwxr-xr-x  2 myself  wheel    3 Sep 21 22:39 soft -> dir
```

[The POSIX specification for the `ln` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ln.html) says:

> If source_file is a symbolic link:
>
> If the `-P` option is in effect, actions shall be performed equivalent to the `linkat()` function with `source_file` as the `path1` argument, the destination path as the `path2` argument, `AT_FDCWD` as the `fd1` and `fd2` arguments, and zero as the `flag` argument.

This text is mostly gibberish unless you know what `linkat()` is. [The OpenBSD manual](https://man.openbsd.org/ln) translates this into

> `-P`
>
> When creating a hard link and the source is a symbolic link, link
> to the symbolic link itself.  The `-P` option overrides any
> previous `-L` options.

... and [the GNU manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/ln-invocation.html) says

> `-P`
> `--physical`
>
> If `-s` is not in effect, and the source file is a symbolic link, create the hard link to the symbolic link itself. On platforms where this is not supported by the kernel, this option creates a symbolic link with identical contents; since symbolic link contents cannot be edited, any file name resolution performed through either link will be the same as if a hard link had been created.

---

Interestingly, GNU `ln` on (Ubuntu) Linux has this in the manual:

> Using `-s` ignores `-L` and `-P`.  Otherwise, the last option specified  controls behavior when a `TARGET` is a symbolic link, **defaulting to `-P`**.

Whereas on OpenBSD and macOS (and presumably on other systems as well), the same GNU `ln` manual says

> Using `-s` ignores `-L` and `-P`.  Otherwise, the last option specified controls
> behavior when a `TARGET` is a symbolic link, **defaulting to `-L`**.

(Another reason to always read the manual on the system you're using rather than on some random page on the internet, which seems to happen far too often.)

Comment: On my (ancient) system `ln` does not have the `-P` option! This does seem to solve the question though.

Comment: @Olius May I ask what system you are running where `ln` does not have a `-P` option? AIX 7.1?

Comment: OS X 10.11.6; `uname -v` gives
`Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Thu Jun 21 20:07:40 PDT 2018; root:xnu-3248.73.11~1/RELEASE_X86_64`. It's the last Apple OS to run on my 2009 dinosaur…

Comment: @Olius Is there a chance you could run GNU `ln` via coreutils on it? Is Homebrew or Fink or MacPorts available on it?

Comment: My friend who needed this is running GNU `ln`. If I remember correctly we were trying to build some funny recursive directory structure when we asked ourselves this question. Not vital for me, but I can definitely get GNU coreutils through Homebrew. Thanks!